# "Pre-built binaries not installable" when installing node package `grpc-js` on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, yarnpkg, grpc-js

I tried installing the following and received an error

```
> yarn add @grpc/grpc-js@^1.4.4
...

> node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.11/node-v102-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.11 and node@17.4.0 (node-v102 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

I tried the following based on some other StackOverflow posts:

- `npm rebuild node-sass`
- Updating `npm` to `17.9.0` (latest available)

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks!

---

Full output

```
$ yarn add @grpc/grpc-js    
yarn add v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning Resolution field "browserslist@4.16.7" is incompatible with requested version "browserslist@^4.17.5"
warning Resolution field "browserslist@4.16.7" is incompatible with requested version "browserslist@^4.19.1"
warning Resolution field "axios@0.21.4" is incompatible with requested version "axios@0.26.0"
warning Resolution field "browserslist@4.16.7" is incompatible with requested version "browserslist@^4.17.3"
warning Resolution field "lodash@4.17.21" is incompatible with requested version "lodash@4.17.15"
warning Resolution field "browserslist@4.16.7" is incompatible with requested version "browserslist@^4.17.5"
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning Pattern ["object-assign@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/home/jeeves/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-object-assign-4.1.1-2109adc7965887cfc05cbbd442cac8bfbb360863-integrity/node_modules/object-assign" as pattern ["object-assign@^4","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.1.1","object-assign@^4.0.1","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.1.0","object-assign@^4.0.1"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @callrail/inti@0.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@nestjs/microservices@^7.0.0".
warning " > @callrail/inti@0.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^6.0.0".
warning " > @callrail/keeper@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@nestjs/microservices@^7.0.0".
warning " > @callrail/keeper@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^6.0.0".
warning " > @honeybadger-io/webpack@1.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>= 4.0.0".
warning " > @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@11.0.0-beta.2" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^6.5.5".
warning " > swagger-ui-express@4.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "express@>=4.0.0".
warning "@nrwl/angular > jasmine-marbles@0.8.4" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^6.5.3".
warning "@nrwl/angular > rxjs-for-await@0.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^6.0.0".
warning "@nrwl/angular > @nrwl/cypress > @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.1".
warning "@nrwl/angular > @nrwl/cypress > @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.0.0".
warning "@nrwl/angular > @nrwl/cypress > @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "babel-loader@^8.0.2".
warning "@nrwl/angular > @nrwl/cypress > @cypress/webpack-preprocessor@5.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4 || ^5".
warning " > @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx@13.1.3" has incorrect peer dependency "@typescript-eslint/parser@~4.33.0".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.4.1".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react@^7.21.5".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4 || ^3 || ^2.3.0 || ^1.7.0".
warning " > file-loader@6.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning " > jscodeshift@0.13.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@^7.1.6".
warning " > webpack-cli@4.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@4.x.x || 5.x.x".
warning "webpack-cli > @webpack-cli/configtest@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@4.x.x || 5.x.x".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[-/24] ⠄ waiting...
[7/24] ⠄ grpc
[3/24] ⠄ @nestjs/core
[-/24] ⠄ waiting...
error /home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.7
node-pre-gyp info using node@17.4.0 | linux | x64
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v102-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.11/node-v102-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.11/node-v102-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.11 and node@17.4.0 (node-v102 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.11/node-v102-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@17.4.0 | linux | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@17.4.0 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
(node:1978323) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/jeeves/.cache/node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/jeeves/.cache/node-gyp/17.4.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/jeeves/.cache/node-gyp/17.4.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@17.4.0 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_trace.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channelz.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channelz_registry.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/connected_channel.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker_registry.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/status_util.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression_args.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression_internal.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/message_compress.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression_gzip.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression_identity.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/http/format_request.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/http/httpcli.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/http/parser.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/buffer_list.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/call_combiner.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/cfstream_handle.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/combiner.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/endpoint.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/endpoint_cfstream.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/endpoint_pair_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/endpoint_pair_uv.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/endpoint_pair_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/error.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/error_cfstream.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll1_linux.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_poll_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/exec_ctx.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/executor.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/executor/mpmcqueue.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/executor/threadpool.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/fork_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/fork_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/gethostname_fallback.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/gethostname_host_name_max.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/gethostname_sysconf.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/grpc_if_nametoindex_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/grpc_if_nametoindex_unsupported.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/internal_errqueue.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iocp_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_custom.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_internal.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_posix_cfstream.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_uv.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/is_epollexclusive_available.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/load_file.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/lockfree_event.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/polling_entity.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_custom.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_set.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_set_custom.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_set_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_uv.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_custom.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resource_quota.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/sockaddr_utils.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_factory_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_mutator.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_linux.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_uv.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_cfstream.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_custom.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_custom.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_custom.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_ifaddrs.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_noifaddrs.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_uv.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_windows.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/time_averaged_stats.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/timer.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/timer_custom.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/timer_generic.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/timer_heap.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/timer_manager.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/timer_uv.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/udp_server.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/unix_sockets_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/unix_sockets_posix_noop.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/wakeup_fd_eventfd.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/wakeup_fd_nospecial.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/wakeup_fd_pipe.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/wakeup_fd_posix.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/json/json.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/json/json_reader.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/json/json_string.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/json/json_writer.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/slice/b64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/slice/percent_encoding.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/slice/slice.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/slice/slice_buffer.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/slice/slice_intern.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/slice/slice_string_helpers.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/api_trace.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/byte_buffer.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/byte_buffer_reader.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call_details.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call_log_batch.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/channel.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/channel_init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/channel_ping.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/channel_stack_type.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/completion_queue.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/completion_queue_factory.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/event_string.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/lame_client.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/metadata_array.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/server.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/validate_metadata.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/version.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/bdp_estimator.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/byte_stream.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/connectivity_state.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/metadata.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/metadata_batch.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/pid_controller.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/static_metadata.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/status_conversion.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/status_metadata.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/timeout_encoding.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/transport.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/transport_op_string.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/uri/uri_parser.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/trace.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/secure/server_secure_chttp2.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/bin_decoder.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/bin_encoder.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_plugin.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/context_list.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/flow_control.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_data.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_goaway.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_ping.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_rst_stream.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_settings.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/frame_window_update.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_encoder.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_parser.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/hpack_table.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/http2_settings.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/huffsyms.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/incoming_metadata.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/parsing.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/stream_lists.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/stream_map.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/varint.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/writing.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/alpn/alpn.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/client/http_client_filter.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/http_filters_plugin.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/message_compress/message_compress_filter.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/http/server/http_server_filter.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/http/httpcli_security_connector.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/context/security_context.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/alts_credentials.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/composite/composite_credentials.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/credentials_metadata.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/fake/fake_credentials.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/google_default/credentials_generic.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/google_default/google_default_credentials.o
In file included from /home/jeeves/.cache/node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/openssl/rsa.h:14,
                 from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/jwt/json_token.h:27,
                 from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/jwt/jwt_credentials.h:25,
                 from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/google_default/google_default_credentials.cc:41:
/home/jeeves/.cache/node-gyp/17.4.0/include/node/openssl/macros.h:155:4: error: #error "OPENSSL_API_COMPAT expresses an impossible API compatibility level"
  155 | #  error "OPENSSL_API_COMPAT expresses an impossible API compatibility level"
      |    ^~~~~
make: *** [grpc.target.mk:548: Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/google_default/google_default_credentials.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.0-37-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/jeeves/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/node" "/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v102-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v102-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v102"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v17.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/home/jeeves/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/node /home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v102-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v102-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v102' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.0-37-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/home/jeeves/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/node" "/home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v17.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.7
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/home/jeeves/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/node /home/jeeves/git/jeeves/gemini-frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --libr
```

Answer (score 0):

`@grpc/grpc-js` does not depend on `grpc`. That error log indicates that another one of your dependencies has a dependency on `grpc`. `grpc` is deprecated, and it is not compatible with Node 17.